# Grunt htmlmin strange behavior with div inside a

Tags: html, gruntjs

I've a template with something like that:

```
<a>
  <div></div>
  <p>another text</p>
</a>
```

with of course `<!doctype html>`

When i launch `grunt server` it works well (no htmlmin) but when i do a `grunt build` with the task `htmlmin`, it output  a wrong html like this:

```
<a></a>
<div></div>
<p>another text</p>
```

I fixed it with this refactoring:

```
<a>
  <span></span>
  <span>another text</span>
</a>
```

I think div and p inside a is html5 valid but why htmlmin don't parse it well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I was using v0.1.1 and the bug is fixed here https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/pull/25